# While Reading Text From Console Window Asynchronously, it needs refresh

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process

I'm launching a cmd tool using C# and I'm showing its output Asynchronously in a text box.

I used the codes [from here](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1236667/Csharp-Read-Text-From-Console-Window-Asynchronousl#answer3).

Everything is working fine. Starting message and stopping message from target cmd tool will insert into the text box. But there is a small problem.

Target cmd tool has a progress bar, but it will not be shown till user press a key inside the tool while it is running, then the user can see for example 50% if press a key again he will see 70% till to the end.

I tried to set a timer and send a key to this process using process handle, but did not get the result I want:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process = new ProcessWrapper("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CmdTool.exe", "someArgs");
    process.OutputDataReceived += (senderz, eventArgs) => SetText($"{textBox1.Text}" + $"{eventArgs.Data}" + Environment.NewLine);
    process.Start();
    processHandle = process.Handle;

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Interval = 5000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!process.HasExited)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(processHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait("k");
    }
}
```

I even tried `Process.Refresh()` on the timer but nothing. How to solve this issue?

Comment: The console window is a cmd.exe application and will not return data until a return is pressed by the user.  That is how the Standard Input Stream works.

Comment: @jdweng so what do you suggest?

Comment: I can't tell what is happening.  Usually issues like this is due to the standard streams are designed.  Windows uses timers to move data between streams.  The code in the link is using FLUSH() to force data to get moved.  I suspect you are missing a FLUSH().  A return automatically does a flush but you are only using SendKeys which probably is not moving the data.